# Direct recording an amp head with my audio interface

Tags: electric-guitar, amplifiers, homerecording

I have a question about direct recording my amp head.
I have a Micro Dark Terror right now and the manual says : " If the Phones jack is not in use, a suitable speaker cabinet must be connected at all times during use. "

If i get the send out to my interface, do i need to use the headphones out or the speaker output at the same time ? Will it damage my amp head or the interface if i only plug the input and the send jacks ?

It's also said that the headphones out has a cabsim and can be used for connecting to a mixer/recording console. Would it sound bad? Am i better off with connecting the send out to the interface ?

Thanks for the upcoming precisions !

Comment: There *must* be a speaker of some sort connected to the amp - either its internal speaker, an external cab., or 'phones. Using 'spkr out' to connect to anything else will damage the amp., and whatever it's connected to. Don't do it! If you use the 'send' out, that should be fine with the interface, but you'll still need a load connected to spkr out, or use the integral speaker. If all eles fails - read the instructions. If that fails, speak to the manufacturer!

Comment: You can connect a loadbox to the speaker out. Loadboxes are designed for exactly this purpose. Just make sure the loadbox impedence (in ohm) is the same as the amp requires (it should be printed near the speaker output socket). The headphone output can be used for recording as it says in the manual. Just try it and see if you like the sound. You don't have to plug sth. into speaker out when there is already something connected to headphone out.